# Line breaks in Sitecore single line textbox

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When I press ENTER in Sitecore single line field textbox it renders TWO linebreaks

```
<br/><br/>
```

This issue appears only in Chrome/Firefox. In IE ENTER leads only to one

Can I disable somehow automatic adding of 
 in these browsers?

Answer (score 3):

Issue is caused by Sitecore Intranet.WebEdit.js

Modifiying this piece of code helped with problem:

```
 if (evt.keyCode == 13 && this.activeElement && this.activeElement.contentEditable() && this.activeElement.parameters["linebreak"] == "br") {
        try {

            if (document.selection != null) {

                var sel = document.selection.createRange();
                sel.pasteHTML('<br />');
                evt.stop();
            }

            if (!Prototype.Browser.IE) {
                evt.srcElement.innerHTML = evt.srcElement.innerHTML + "<br/>";
                evt.stop();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good answer Jack. Will keep this as my fav ques.